# Create JUnit TestSuite in a non-static way

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am seeking for a way to create and let run a JUnit TestSuite in a non-static fashion.

Currently I am doing something like this:

```
public class MyTestSuite {
    public static TestSuite suite() {
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
        suite.addTest(...);
        suite.addTest(...);
        // ....
        return suite;
    }
}
```

I am doing this because I am creating the TestCases I am adding to the suite programmatically.
With this solution I am facing the problem that my class MyTestSuite is never instantiated. I would like to wire it with a spring container, e.g. using

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={...})
@Transactional
```

but I see no way of telling the SpringJUnit4ClassRunner that it should also execute my programmatic tests.

Thanks for your help!
Erik

Comment: +1 ditto.  I too am looking to do this

Answer (score 2):

Why use a suite at all?  Seems simpler to put your tests in their own subdirectory and have an ant (or whatever build tool you're using) target that runs just the tests found there.

Comment: This seems like a better idea. +1

Answer (score 1):

You could try and have MyTestSuite as part of your spring context (the test context) and fire an init method on it which would add your programmatic tests. That would allow you to inject MyTestSuite which has this programmtic tests added when it is instantiated by spring.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

For JUnit3-style `suite` methods, JUnit does not create an instance of the class; it calls the method and calls `run(TestResult)` on the returned object.

`SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` is a JUnit4 Runner class, so it cannot be used to affect the behavior of JUnit3-style test suites. Spring does not provide a JUnit4-style suite implementation. If you want each of the test cases to use `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`, your best option is to upgrade them to JUnit4.

If you are asking how you add your Spring tests to `MyTestSuite`:

```
public class MyTestSuite {
    public static Test suite() {
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
        suite.addTest(...);
        suite.addTest(...);
        suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(ExampleSpringTest.class));
        // ....
        return suite;
    }
}
```